# How to show the order number in which the checkboxes are clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to output the order number in which the checkboxes are checked. Whichever checkbox is checked first should show "a" beside it, whichever is checked second should show "b" beside it and so on.. Can anyone help?

```
<ul class="dropdown-content checkboxes">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Billy
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Jacob
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Bob
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Alexandren
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Erren
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Stewgart
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Jillian
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" />
      Other
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you add the code you've attempted to your question, please. Welcome to SO, btw. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much Andy. I'll take care of these things by next time. For now I got the solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This keeps track of the order of items clicked in an array. When one is deselected, it `splice`s the array and reorders the alphabet letters according to the order of the array

```js
let alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(el => {
  el.innerHTML += '<span class="letter"> </span>'
})
let checkedItems=[]
document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]').forEach(el => {
el.value = el.closest('label').innerText.trim()
  el.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let n = el.closest('label').innerText.trim();
    if (!e.target.checked)  checkedItems.splice(checkedItems.indexOf(n),1)
    else checkedItems.push(n);
    document.querySelectorAll('.letter').forEach( l=> l.innerHTML = '')
    checkedItems.forEach((n,i) => {
    document.querySelector(`input[value=${n}]`).closest('li').querySelector('.letter').innerHTML = alpha[i]
    })
 
  });

});
```

```css
.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-content checkboxes">
  <li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Billy</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Jacob</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Bob</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Alexandren</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Erren</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Stewgart</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Jillian</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Other</label>
  </li>
```

Comment: On unchecking any checkbox the letter is still visible and if unchecked the first checked box then it says 'undefined'. I tried it on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can add checked checkboxes at the end of an array, and remove them when get unchecked. By doing so, it will automatically adjust letters on checked boxes like so:

```js
const cb = document.querySelectorAll('ul.checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]');
const order = [];
const onInput = e =>
{
  const data = e.target;
  const index = order.indexOf(data);
  if (index != -1)
    order.splice(index, 1);

  if (e.target.checked)
    order[order.length] = data;

  for(let i = 0; i < cb.length; i++)
  {
    const index = order.indexOf(cb[i]);
    cb[i].parentNode.setAttribute("num", String.fromCharCode(65 + index));
  }
}
for(let i = 0; i < cb.length; i++)
  cb[i].addEventListener("input", onInput);
```

```css
.checkboxes label[num]:not([num = "@"]):before
{
  content: attr(num);
}

.checkboxes label:before
{
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-content checkboxes">
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Billy</label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Jacob</label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Bob</label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Alexandren</label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Erren</label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Stewgart</label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Jillian</label>
</li>
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />Other</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

You set the value for each checkbox.

`<input type="checkbox" value="1" />`

Whenever it will be checked, it can trigger an event and you can get the value.

```
$("#checkbox").change(function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    var value = $(this).val();
});
```